# Using Variable in Regex Character Set

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

i'm trying to use a variable (save) as a regex character set but keep getting null

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var save = arr[1];
  var rgx = /[save]/gi;
  return arr[0].match(rgx).join('') == arr[0]; 

}

mutation(["Mary", "Army"]);
```

Goal of the function is to see if all the letters of arr[1] are contained in arr[0] by returning true or false. Function does work as i want it to when i manually put arr[1] into the character set (returns true in this situation), just cant get it to work with the variable.

Comment: Why can't you use normal logic instead of regex? Now you will have to escape all `-` and `^` and `\ `, etc.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it. But it's not a good idea either.

Comment: Honestly there is certainly easier ways so i completely agree but i went down this road and wanted to see if using a variable in regex was possible

Answer (score 1):

Your exact current approach won't work (I think) due to it not being possible to build a regex pattern using `/.../` notation with a variable.  But, we can still use `RegExp` to build the pattern.  For the sample data you showed us, here is a regex pattern which would work:

```
^(?!.*[^Mary]).*$`
```

In other words, we can assert, on the second string `Army`, that all its characters can be found in the first string `Mary`.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var save = arr[1];
  var rgx = "^(?!.*[^" + save + "]).*$";
  var re = new RegExp(rgx, "gi");
  return re.test(arr[0]);

}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Army"]));
console.log(mutation(["Jon Skeet", "Tim Biegeleisen"]));
```